# How to post a django request to external server

Tags: python, django, rest, request

Hi so I have this method in django views to post the file to a different server. I get an HTTP 415 error complaining about the media type of the request. I have debugged the request and copied and pasted its contents in fiddler. When I posted the same from fiddler it worked. So I don't understand why it does not work using python requests package.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url=settings.WEBSERVICES_URL+'validate'
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:9090/validate',data=request)
        r2 = requests.get('http://localhost:9090/test')
        return render_to_response("upload.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response("upload.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9090/validate', data=request.POST)
```

You are passing a full `django.http.HttpRequest` object to `requests.post`, when you only need its post data.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. The problem now is that the POST url which is localhost:8000 is not replaced when requests.post is called. Since the form is posted to localhost:8000/upload initially to reach the upload method in views the POST url is not correct. I would expect that requests would replace it but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation of requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post) it says about the `data` keyword:

> **data** – (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request.

Django's `request` object is an instance of [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).You should try to put the necessary data in a dictionary and pass it to `post()`.