# Django Post to External Server

Tags: django, python-requests

I am relatively new to Django/Python. I am currently developing a Django system to track entries to a modelling system our company developed.

Clients should be able to post model run data to a database on our server. The data will be coming from a python script. I was able to make it work on my system using `somemodelname.objects.get_or_create`, but this will not work externally. I understand I should use a package such as requests and found: [How to post a django request to external server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865986/how-to-post-a-django-request-to-external-server). However, this assumes the django code (views, etc) is accessible from the client computer.

How can I make this work so the client data is posted from a python script to the Django database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good use of a RESTful API. [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) and [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are both good packages to use with Django.

Basically, with an API, you can expose your database through urls. You'll have a url like: `mysitename.com/api/mymodel` that can handle different HTTP methods. If you called that with a `POST` verb, your view would create a new record for your `mymodel` model. Thus, when your client computer generates the data in a python script, you would use `[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)` to send the data in a `POST` request to the url endpoint, which would create the record in the database.

Comment: I have come back to this project and still don't have a working version. It correctly posts the values to the test page form ("http://httpbin.org/post"), but gives me the whole html code for my page when I run: r.contents (where r is the request). I've tested the status code and it runs correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: One of the challenges may be that the database (in postgresql) is expecting an "id" field and id value for a field with a foreign key. I think these could be input explicitly server-side.

Comment: Additional info: I have a button on the page. Before pressing the button, the network log says request type is "GET". This switches to "POST" after pressing the button and the form fields actually appear in the log. There is a field for the button, which I have attempted to include in my request, but this doesn't work either.