# Django rest framework pull in external json data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If i want to pull in an external api to django REST framework. Whats the best way to go about it? I already have the json, but how can I construct a read only api endpoint for this. I'm using the REST framework for a app server, and its handling the auth with the external api, but I want to pass the json data through the REST framework.

Comment: can you be more specific. this is a bit vague so hard to make any suggestions

Comment: is it a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865986/how-to-post-a-django-request-to-external-server?

Answer (score 0):

You may use as below.

```
class MyApi(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        external_api_url = "" 
        res = urllib.urlopen(external_api_url).read()
        data = json.loads(res)
        return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

For read only you endpoint you can use below code:

```
from reset_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ExtenalViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        api_url = "/api/externalurl/"
        res = urllib.urlopen(api_url).read()
        data = json.loads(res)
        return Response(data)
```